# How to debug this code written to split an array by space?

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that get a sentence and split its words by a delimiter(space);so I've wrote the code below but it doesn't seem to be working properly. any idea's how to debug this code? 
for example:

```
input:
    meet me tonight
desired output: 
    meet 
    me
    tonight
given output:  
    meet
    me ton 
    ght
```

I'm really confused why the output is not what I expect. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int BUFFER_SIZE=255;

int main()
{       
   char* buffer;
   buffer = new char[255];
   cout << "enter a statement:" << endl;
   cin.getline(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
   int q=0, numofwords=1;
   while(buffer[q] != '\0')
   {
      if(buffer[q] == ' ') 
         numofwords++;
      q++;
   }
   char** wordsArray;
   wordsArray = new char* [numofwords];  

   int lenofeachword = 0, num = 0;
   int* sizeofwords = new int [numofwords];
   for(int i=0; i<q; i++)
   {
      if(buffer[i]==' ')
      {
         sizeofwords[num] = lenofeachword;
         wordsArray[num] = new char[lenofeachword];
         num++; 
      }else
         lenofeachword++;
   }
   sizeofwords[num] = lenofeachword;  
   wordsArray[num] = new char[lenofeachword]; 
   int k=0;
   for(int i=0; i<numofwords; i++)
   {
      for(int j=0; j<sizeofwords[i]; j++)
      {
         wordsArray[i][j] = buffer[k];
         k++;
      }
      k++;
   }

   for(int i=0; i<numofwords; i++)
   {
      for(int j=0; j<sizeofwords[i]; j++)
      {
         cout << wordsArray[i][j];
      }
      cout << endl; 
   }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265730/receiving-segmentation-fault-with-a-program-to-split-sentences/22266198#22266198 it seems to be the same ,hope it helps

Comment: Do you have a debugger? The first thing to do is to step through the code and see what it does with real input.

Comment: everything seems correct but the output is not just what it must be.

Comment: Run this a few times with some sample text and post the results. It could help understand where the error lies. Also, how do you propose to deal with two spaces in a row? Are they counted as two words?

Comment: For real use, you want to read the input into an `std::string`, then do the splitting with a `std::istringstream` and deposit the results into a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this snippet (comment):

```
if(buffer[i]==' ')
{
    sizeofwords[num] = lenofeachword;
    wordsArray[num] = new char[lenofeachword];
    num++;
}else{
    lenofeachword++; // <- this keeps increasing
}
```

So this snippet will skip a lot of the strings and possibly cause a seg fault somewhere along the line:

```
for(int i=0; i<numofwords;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<sizeofwords[i];j++)
    {
        wordsArray[i][j]=buffer[k];
        k++;
    }
    k++;
}
```

Also if this is c++, then why are you still using c-style to write this program? A simple [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/) with [strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) will do this in less lines of code